# Is OpenGL's execution model synchronous, within a single context?

Tags: opengl

Given a single OpenGL context (and therefore can only be accessed by a single CPU thread at a time), if I execute two OpenGL commands, is there a guarantee that the second command will see the results of the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases, this is true. OpenGL commands largely behave as if all prior commands have completed fully and completely. Notable places where this matters include:

- Blending. Blending is often an operation that is very sensitive to order. Blending not only works correctly between rendering commands, it works correctly *within* a rendering command. Triangles in a draw call are explicitly ordered, and blending will blend things in the order that the primitives appear in the draw call
- Reading from a previously rendered framebuffer image. If you render to an image, you can unbind that framebuffer and bind the image as a texture and read from it, without doing anything special.
- Reading data from a buffer that was used in a transform feedback operation. Nothing special needs to go between the command that generates the feedback data and the command reading it (outside of unbinding the buffer from the TF operation and binding it in the proper target for reading).

Obviously, waiting for the GPU to complete its commands before letting the CPU send more sounds incredibly slow. This is why OpenGL works under the "as if" rule: implementations must behave "as if" they were synchronous. So implementations spend a lot of time tracking which operations will produce which data, so that if you do something that will require something to wait on the GPU to produce that data, it can do so.

So you should try to avoid immediately trying to read data generated by some command. Put some distance between the generator and the consumer.

Now, I said above that this is true for "the vast majority of cases". So there are some back-doors. [In no particular order](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model):

- Attempting to read from an image that you are currently using as a render target is normally forbidden. But [under specific circumstances](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Texture_barrier), it can be allowed, typically through the use of the `glTextureBarrier` command. This command ensures the execution and visibility of previously submitted rendering commands to subsequent commands. Failure to do this correctly results in undefined behavior.
- The contents of buffers or images that are subject to writes (atomic or otherwise) from what we can call [incoherent memory access operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access). These include image store/atomic operations, SSBO store/atomic operations, and atomic counter operations. Unless you employ various tools, specific to the particulars of who is reading the data and their relationship to the writer, you will get undefined behavior.
- [Sync objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sync_Objects). By their nature, sync objects bypass the in-order execution model because... that's their point: to allow the user to be exposed directly to how the GPU executes stuff.
- [Asynchronous pixel transfers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) are an odd case. They don't actually break the in-order nature of the OpenGL memory model. But because you are reading into/writing from storage that you don't have direct access to, the implementation can hide the fact that it will take some time to read the data. So if you invoke a pixel transfer to a buffer, and then immediately try to read from the buffer, the system has to put a wait between those two commands. But if you issue a bunch of commands between the pixel transfer and the consumer of it, and those commands don't use the range being consumed, then the cost of the pixel transfer can appear to be negligible. Sync objects can be employed to know when the transfer is actually over.